# Automatically save an image from an email to photo album in ios 14 shortcuts

Tags: automation, shortcut, ios14

For my work i get an automated email every week with my schedule attached in the email i was wondering if it is possible using the new ios 14 shortcuts automation to automatically save the image from the email to an album named schedule in camera roll can someone tell me how i can do this.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, there is no way to do it automatically, even with the shortcuts (I could be wrong). I do know certain apps (WhatsApp), for example can do auto saving of images. If you have that application, perhaps the e-mail sender can use that medium instead of an e-mail? That will at least solve half of your issue.

As per auto grouping; if you have a Mac Laptop running Catalina, you can create a Smart Albums of the pictures you want grouped together.

I'm sure other persons will comment on this; I'm interested if others can come up with a more concise solution.